# SQL : picking distinct values based on rank

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find out the rank/row_number of IDs in a dataset and assign one ID to one cluster based on rank. The catch is, the same ID can be rank 1 for two different clusters. In this case, if one ID has already been assigned to one cluster, then the next rank should be assigned to the other cluster.

| CLUSTER | ID | RNK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CLST1 | ID1 | 1 |
| CLST1 | ID2 | 2 |
| CLST2 | ID1 | 1 |
| CLST2 | ID2 | 2 |

In this dataset, if ID1 is assigned to CLST1, then ID2 must be picked for CLST2 based on rank. How can I achieve this in Redshift?

Comment: Please don't tag spam; Tag the RDBMS you expect an answer for. As **clearly** explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data. No one can copy/paste data from a picture. Sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Sample data is great, but we need the expected result as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplicate rank numbers nor gaps use `row_number()`.
The following script shows the difference between `rank()`, `dense_rank()` and `row_number()` when there is a duplicate value.

> ```
> select
>   id,
>   rank() over (order by id) "rank",
>   dense_rank() over (order by id) "dense_rank",
>   row_number() over (order by id) "row_number"
> from t;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | rank | dense_rank | row_number
> -: | ---: | ---------: | ---------:
>  1 |    1 |          1 |          1
>  2 |    2 |          2 |          2
>  3 |    3 |          3 |          3
>  3 |    3 |          3 |          4
>  4 |    5 |          4 |          5
>  5 |    6 |          5 |          6
> ```

MySQL *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=862637720a11c9efae9032cb88b72270)*
PostgreSQL *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=862637720a11c9efae9032cb88b72270)*

Comment: Generating values is fine. The problem here is that the same ID must not be assigned to different clusters. If rank 1 has already been picked, then rank 2 should get picked next time, instead of rank 1 getting picked again